# How are updates rolled out?

Tags: ether, ethereum-classic, eth-2.0, forks, upgrading

if an update to Ethereum or any other cryptocurrency is rolled out, how to ensure that everyone in the network is running the same 'version'.
Especially if the update is not backward-compatible with previous versions ?